# Imitate a iPhone swipe view on a webapp (like the weather app)

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, html, web-applications

I'm trying to find a Javascript snippet that I can archive the UIScrollView + UIPageControl effect of the iOS using Javascript and CSS3.

Generating the page control to a dot to each view and do the switching is very easy, but the complicated part it is to do the elastic movement.

[image: UIPageControl]

I would want to do this myself, but it seems to much work to me, like hours of work, tried googling, but I not found anything. I don't like JQuery but the mobile framework doesn't seems to do this.

[image: UIScrollView UIPageControl]

If I had to do this by myself, do you guys have any suggested approach? I'm thinking in using a parent div, with a bunch of divs inside for each view. Use the parent with overflow: hidden;
and attach event to the parent view and listen to drags and bind to the horizontal scroll offset. This would be a good way? or using css transitions with `left` or translate-x would be more smooth?

EDIT:
This is what I tried (not working very well): [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/pUa75/)

Comment: This looks promising: http://swipejs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yeah,

Im not sure about touch swipes, although i think the 'activate' or 'touchstart' handler might be useful. Using CSS3 transitions to achieve the elastic movement is quite smooth, just alter the left or right style property of your internal div and the transfom will move from its current position to where you need it to be. 
This is not the worlds bestt example but have a look here

villasanrafael.eu/Gallery.php